# Jmeter Concurrent & Arrival Thread Group Setup

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Spec:

100 User, with arrival rate of 10 users every 1 minute

Runtime: 24 hours, with 100 new users every 1 hour

Concurrent TCP connections : 100

Setup

[Arrival Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN1Rd.png)

[Concurrent Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUQiE.png)

Comment: Is the above setup correct. New to using Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stick to a single thread group only, i.e. [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/), your combined "spec" would result into:

[image]

I've also highlighted "Thread Iterations Limit" input, if you want `100 new users every 1 hour` you need to put the number of iterations for a single user so after completing that number of iterations the associated thread would be shut down and a new one will be started.

Also this `Concurrent TCP connections : 100` bit may or may not be achievable depending on the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) you're using, in case of [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) which is configured to download [Embedded Resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) the number of connections may be up to 6x times higher so it's better to check it using i.e. [Server Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listener

Comment: Hey @Dmitri T, thank you so much for replying. Is there any way to mssge you privately. Completely new to Jmeter. Need to ask some basic queries.